# How to create a dynamic greeting?

Tags: command-line, bashrc, random

Recently made the switch to Linux/command line, and I'm having trouble creating a dynamic greeting for terminal out of a list of predetermined possibilities.

I tried the following, but it appears as if I can't figure out the correct syntax for the random.choice function I've been using.

```
a="Affirmative, Dave. I read you."
b="Good afternoon, Mr. Avers. Everything is going extremely well."
c="My instructor was Mr. Langley, and he taught me to sing a song. If you'd like to hear it, I can sing it for you."
random.choice(('a', 'b', 'c')) | echo
```

Any script or creating-questions advice is welcome.

Edit: I added these lines to ~/.bash_aliases, not ~/.bashrc as I don't want to mess with that file just yet.

I was looking to get one of these greetings when opening terminal, and indeed, I didn't realize that random.choice was a python function.

Using @MelBurslan 's code worked perfectly, but thank you to everyone who commented.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are doing in more detail. Have you added these lines in `~/.bashrc`? Do you expect one of the three messages to be echoed each time you open a terminal? Each time you log in? Have you defined `random.choice` somewhere or is that what you are asking?

Comment: `random.choice` is not a python function?

Comment: You are confusing bash with python. `random.choice` is a python function. similar effect can be attained using bash, as in the answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing bash with python. random.choice is a python function. A similar effect can be attained using bash like this:

```
greeting=("Affirmative, Dave. I read you." "Good afternoon, Mr. Avers. Everything is going extremely well." "Do you want me to sing a song for you ?")
index=$(( RANDOM % ${#greeting[@]} ))
echo ${greeting[${index}]}
```